# Matrix Math with VBA (System of Linear Equations)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, math, matrix

I'm looking for a little help performing some matrix mathematics in Excel's VBA.  I've read a ton of replies that suggest using the Excel worksheet but I'm hoping to solve this within the VBA code itself.

Although my application is much larger, let's say I have a system of linear equations that I need to solve:

```
  x1 +   x2 = 8
2*x1 + 4*x2 = 100
```

This can be solved with the simple matrix formula A*x = B or x = A^(-1) * B where,

```
A = [1, 1; 2, 4]
B = [8; 100]
```

If you solve this, you'll find x1 = -34 and x2 = 42.  In terms of the matrix, then:

```
X = [-34; 42]
```

Using Excel's worksheets alongside its MMULT and MINVERSE functions makes this easy and I've gotten it to work just fine.  My problem is I'm needing to do this calculation inside a VBA function.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
Dim A(0 To 1, 0 To 1) As Single
Dim B(0 To 0, 0 To 1) As Single
Dim X(0 To 0, 0 To 1) As Single

A(0, 0) = 1
A(1, 0) = 1
A(0, 1) = 2
A(1, 1) = 4

B(0, 0) = 8
B(0, 1) = 100

X = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A), B)
```

Unfortunately, the last line yields a "Compile error: can't assign to array" message.  I think it's because I have to specify each element of the array one at a time, but the worksheet functions are array functions.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Look in the locals window (if you can't see, click View > Locals, and to get to the right part either step through your code with F8 or set a break-point) to see the values of the variables just before the msgbox - that will tell you precisely what X is and how to index it. It could be the array returned by MMult is actually a 'vector' array (i.e. 1 dimensional) and so should be indexed as simply X(0) and X(1).

Comment: That worked!  For reference, the MMult appears to store the values in X(1,1) and X(2,1) which makes sense--I just didn't think to check the Locals window.  Good catch!  And you're welcome about the algorithm--I used it all the time in excel spreadsheets but never had a need in VBA.  Thanks again!  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things:

The same rule applies as in actual mathematics: `B` must be a vertical array for matrix multiplication to be possible in your case. Declare it as

```
Dim B(0 To 1, 0 To 0) As Single
```

and initialize it accordingly. Also, just declare

```
Dim X As Variant
```

since the `MMult` returns a Variant array. This is what was causing your original error.

Comment: Any reason why you'd want to declare it as a Single instead of a Double?